# Data not being added to Parse?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to send coordinate data to my cloud in Parse however I could not do it for some reason. I got all my fields name correct.

Here is the fields : 
[image]

coordinate is undefined but the rest are okay.
Here is my code to push it :

```
class AddYourOwnCarWash : UIViewController
{
    var servicedownpicker : DownPicker!
    var ratingdownpicker : DownPicker!
    var carGeoPoint = PFGeoPoint()


   let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(addresstextfield.text!){
        placemark, error in
        if let error = error {
            self.showAlert("ERROR", message: error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        //self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        if let  placemark = placemark{
            if placemark.count > 0 {
                let placemark = placemark.first!
                let coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D = placemark.location!.coordinate
                if let country = placemark.country, state = placemark.administrativeArea{
                    if let city = placemark.locality{
                       carwashobject["address"] = "\(city), \(state), \(country)"
                        print(coordinates.latitude)
                        print(coordinates.longitude)

                        self.carGeoPoint.latitude = coordinates.latitude
                        self.carGeoPoint.longitude = coordinates.longitude
                        carwashobject["coordinate"] = self.carGeoPoint

                        //self.stopActivityIndicator()
                    }else {
                         carwashobject["address"] = "\(state), \(country)"
                         carwashobject["coordinate"] = self.carGeoPoint
                        //self.stopActivityIndicator()
                    }
                } else {
                    self.showAlert("ERROR", message:"Be more specific in location")
                }
            } else {
                self.showAlert("ERROR", message:"Unable to find location")
            }
        } else {
            self.showAlert("ERROR", message: "Unable to find location")
        }
    }
    carwashobject["car"] = cartextfield.text
    carwashobject["price"] = Double(pricingtextfield.text!)
    carwashobject["service"] = servicestextfield.text
    carwashobject["rating"] = Double(ratingtextfield.text!)

    carwashobject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        print("Object has been saved.")

    }

     performSegueWithIdentifier("backtomain", sender: self)
}
```

[image]

coordinates.latitude and coordinates.longitude are not nil
github : https://github.com/ariff20/WashAndShine

**So why is not being added?**

Comment: I don't see where you actually add the object to Parse. All I see is the object creation.

Comment: Agree with Eric, you never saved this information.

Comment: @pbush25 edited the question with the proper info but still not being added?

Comment: @EricD. edited the question with the proper info.Thanks for spotting it but  the fields latitude and longitude are still not being added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse using own class for localization, for example:

```
let point = PFGeoPoint(latitude:40.0, longitude:-30.0)
```

For editing you can try this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
     var carGeoPoint = PFGeoPoint()

.......
```

And then in your function:

```
@IBAction func addcarwash(sender: AnyObject)
{
    var carwashobject = PFObject(className: "CarWash")
    let locManager = CLLocationManager()
   print(nametextfield.text)
    print(addresstextfield.text)
    print(cartextfield.text)
    print(pricingtextfield.text)
    print(servicestextfield.text)
    print(ratingtextfield.text)
    locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    carwashobject["name"] = nametextfield.text
    carwashobject["address"] = addresstextfield.text
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(addresstextfield.text!){
        placemark, error in
        if let error = error {
            self.showAlert("ERROR", message: error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        //self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        if let  placemark = placemark{
            if placemark.count > 0 {
                let placemark = placemark.first!
                let coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D = placemark.location!.coordinate
                if let country = placemark.country, state = placemark.administrativeArea{
                    if let city = placemark.locality{
                        carwashobject["address"] = "\(city), \(state), \(country)"
                        print(coordinates.latitude)
                        print(coordinates.longitude)

                        self.carGeoPoint.latitude = coordinates.latitude
                        self.carGeoPoint.longitude = coordinates.longitude
                        print("***********************")
                        print(self.carGeoPoint.latitude)
                        print(self.carGeoPoint.longitude)
                        carwashobject["coor"] = self.carGeoPoint
                        carwashobject["car"] = cartextfield.text
                        carwashobject["price"] = Double(pricingtextfield.text!)
                        carwashobject["service"] = servicestextfield.text
                        carwashobject["rating"] = Double(ratingtextfield.text!)

                        carwashobject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                            print("Object has been saved.")

                        }

                        //self.stopActivityIndicator()
                    }else {
                        carwashobject["address"] = "\(state), \(country)"
                        carwashobject["coor"] = self.carGeoPoint
                        //self.stopActivityIndicator()
                    }
                } else {
                    self.showAlert("ERROR", message:"Be more specific in location")
                }
            } else {
                self.showAlert("ERROR", message:"Unable to find location")
            }
        } else {
            self.showAlert("ERROR", message: "Unable to find location")
        }
    }



     performSegueWithIdentifier("backtomain", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: okay I have tried using PFGeoPoint but the field is still empty even after saving the object.Why is that?

Comment: I have to see all the code, the reason can be multiple. From the bad initialization to wrong saving. If u can up the picture or update your code post i can answer you.

Comment: Maybe your uploading data getting lose before saving on database. I updated my code. Let me know if that going to work.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I'm starting to think it's a problem because of the field coordinate. Why are the other fields okay?

Comment: `print(coordinates.latitude)`
 `print(coordinates.longitude)` they have results right?

Comment: yes they do have coordinates.  You can download my project from github here and check for yourself : https://github.com/ariff20/WashAndShine

Comment: I think the project on github is out of date. Check if you have any classes with the same name on the parse also, sometimes that creates issues like this.

Comment: Just checked , nope all is different . This is reallly frustrating

Comment: That looks interesting, i can only suggest you now to do how i edited in my code now. Just move all rest parsing data to save in to the placemark.

Comment: woops this is embarassing , forgot to push it lol . fixed it now.Anyways I'm trying to use a cash textfield delegate but it keeps giving me an error saying the object is nil . Would you mind to take a look?

Comment: Still there isn't file to check :) did u try my last solution? Which was the result?

Comment: omg I am so bad at git. Okay this time it should work .Did not understand your solution . Pls take a look at my github now.

Comment: Amazing! Care to explain what you have changed?

Comment: Like i said before, just moved saveInBackground function :)